How do I check if any user has executed a time travel query in BigQuery
in our team, we use the default 7 days for time-travel. We are in logical bytes pricing model. We wish to switch to Physical bytes pricing model. To make it more cost effective, we want to evaluate if any user have used time-travel feature in the last 6 months and hopefully change the 7 day setting to 2 day setting.
How do i check -

if any users used time-travel feature in the last 6 months.
Determine if their use-cases get affected by changing setting from 7 days to 2 days.

This will help us switch to Physical bytes billing model and save us some costs.

An option could be look in the audit logs and analyze the query text, but it requires the audit logs enabled and you have a log retention of 6 months or exported the logs to BigQuery. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs

For the second question, it's not a BigQuery question, as this can apply to any team policy or env setting change in an organization. The best way to ensure minimal impact (because I doubt you can have non-existent one) is to talk with the involved teams and see how many times they needed TT and for how long ago in the past. Then ask if they had any situation where 7 days was not enough and discuss a reduction to 5 (or lower but higher than 2) days (I recommend to do it in stages, for example first 7 days, then 5 or 4, depending on the discussion, then 2, not from 7 to 2 so "suddenly").

You can't know like this. You must see in the logs if a job contains a query with a time travel usage. However, by default you have only the 30 last days. If you want more, retain the logs longer.
For the second questions, Time Travel is not a "happy path feature". It helps to fix unexpected issues. It's an emergency solution
If you think you have a use case that can break your data, you have to perform a BigQUery snapshot and then apply your risky transformation
